# Google Spreadsheet Apps Script - HTML Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Is there any way I can write the output of the html object directly to a cell, instead of a dialog box.  If it's not possible, I am trying to figure a way so that I can capture the output from the dialog box and paste it into a cell.  My goal is to include javascript into the html, evaluate the code, and send the output to a cell on the spreadsheet.  The below code is from Apps Script tutorial (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

gs.code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: 'Open', functionName: 'openDialog'}];
  ss.addMenu('Dialog', menu);
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  ss.show(html);
}
```

index.html:

```
< input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just getActiveSpreadsheet from your html code and write it to the cell you want from there.

Comment: Can you explain to me or provide an example on how to get the data from "openDialog" or some other ways of getting the data. Sorry, I am very new to Google Apps script.  So far I can only write the actual script, (before it is being evaluated), by using html.getContent () to the cell.

Comment: look up in htmlService help how to call a gas server-side function. that function will then do the spreadsheet writes. see here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: I believed this is what I am looking for.  Thanks so much for your help!  So... google.script.run.YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME(); runs Google app-script from the html file (index.html in this example).